# Assertion failed TensorFlow when I have more data

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, classification

Hi I am very new to TensorFlow and I have an error that I dont understand. I have a script that generates a binary classifier. My total dataset contains more than 5M entries with positive negative outcomes. The positive is around 7.5% of the total data. When I run the classifier for less than 800k of my entries everything is cool. When I try to train using all of my data to just more than these 800k I get the error

```
1/367 [..............................] - ETA: 2:43 - loss: 0.0000e+00 - TruePositive: 8.0000Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\My Programs\Python\DeepLearningFraudAnalysis\PythonFraudAnalysis\KerasClassifierV1.py", line 91, in <module>
    model.fit( X_train, y_train, epochs = epochs_no, batch_size = batch_size )
  File "C:\Users\alexandros\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Users\alexandros\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py", line 54, in quick_execute
    tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'assert_greater_equal/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "d:\My Programs\Python\DeepLearningFraudAnalysis\PythonFraudeAnalysis\KerasClassifierV1.py", line 91, in <module>
      model.fit( X_train, y_train, epochs = epochs_no, batch_size = batch_size )
    File "C:\Users\alexandros\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\alexandros\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1384, in fit
      tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
    File "C:\Users\alexandros\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1021, in train_function
      return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "C:\Users\alexandros\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1010, in step_function
      outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "C:\Users\alexandros\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1000, in run_step
      outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "C:\Users\alexandros\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 864, in train_step
      return self.compute_metrics(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "C:\Users\alexandros\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 957, in compute_metrics
      self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "C:\Users\alexandros\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\keras\engine\compile_utils.py", line 459, in update_state
      metric_obj.update_state(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=mask)
    File "C:\Users\alexandros\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\keras\utils\metrics_utils.py", line 70, in decorated
      update_op = update_state_fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\alexandros\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\keras\metrics.py", line 178, in update_state_fn
      return ag_update_state(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\alexandros\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\keras\metrics.py", line 1073, in update_state
      return metrics_utils.update_confusion_matrix_variables(
    File "C:\Users\alexandros\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\keras\utils\metrics_utils.py", line 602, in update_confusion_matrix_variables
      tf.compat.v1.assert_greater_equal(
Node: 'assert_greater_equal/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert'
assertion failed: [predictions must be >= 0] [Condition x >= y did not hold element-wise:] [x (sequential/dense_2/Sigmoid:0) = ] [[0.438505232][0.424332052][0.430545419]...] [y (Cast_2/x:0) = ] [0]
         [[{{node assert_greater_equal/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_870]
PS D:\My Programs\Python\DeepLearningFraudAnalysis\PythonFraudAnalysis>
```

The full script is bellow

```
import constants
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib 
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, MinMaxScaler
from pymongo import MongoClient
import numpy as np
import time
import sys

start_time = time.time()

# Making a Connection with MongoClient
try:
    conn = MongoClient()
    print("Connected successfully!!!")
except:  
    print("Could not connect to MongoDB")

# database
db = conn["fraud_database"]
# collection
avgSamplescollection = db["fraud_samples_avg"]

avgSamplesCount = avgSamplescollection.count_documents({})
limit = 1000000
avgSamplesCount = limit

npAvgSamples = np.zeros( shape = ( constants.TRAINING_DAYS + 1, avgSamplesCount ) )
idx = 0
totalPositiveSamples = 0
for avgSample in avgSamplescollection.find().batch_size( 500000 ).limit(limit):
    for j in range( constants.TRAINING_DAYS ):
        val = avgSample[ 'data' ][ j ][ 'Close' ]
        npAvgSamples[ j ][ idx ] = val
    npAvgSamples[ constants.TRAINING_DAYS ][ idx ] = avgSample[ 'tag']
    totalPositiveSamples += avgSample[ 'tag' ]
    idx += 1
    print( "loaded:" + str(idx) + " samples out of:" + str( avgSamplesCount ) + " percentage:" + str( idx /avgSamplesCount * 100 ) + "%" )

scaler = MinMaxScaler()
npAvgSamples = scaler.fit_transform(npAvgSamples)
npAvgSamples = npAvgSamples.transpose()

totalNegativeSamples = avgSamplesCount - totalPositiveSamples
print("Total positive samples:" + str( totalPositiveSamples ) + " Total negative samples:" + str( totalNegativeSamples ) + " Total samples" +  str( avgSamplesCount ) )

inputX = npAvgSamples[ :, 0 : constants.TRAINING_DAYS ]
outputY = npAvgSamples[ :, constants.TRAINING_DAYS ]

#inputX = scaler.fit_transform( inputX )

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split( inputX, outputY, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 40 )

class_weight = { 0: totalNegativeSamples/avgSamplesCount, 1:totalPositiveSamples/avgSamplesCount }

model = Sequential()
model.add( Dense( constants.TRAINING_DAYS + constants.TRAINING_DAYS / 2, input_dim=constants.TRAINING_DAYS, activation='relu' ) )
model.add( Dense( constants.TRAINING_DAYS / 2, activation='relu' ) )
model.add( Dense( 1, activation = 'sigmoid' ) )

METRICS = [
      keras.metrics.TruePositives( name='TruePositive' ),
      #keras.metrics.FalsePositives( name='FalsePositive' ),
      #keras.metrics.TrueNegatives( name='TrueNegative' ),
      #keras.metrics.FalseNegatives( name='FalseNegative' ), 
      #keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy( name='Accuracy' ),
      #keras.metrics.Precision( name='Precision' ),
      #keras.metrics.Recall( name='Recall' ),
      #keras.metrics.AUC( name='auc' ),
      #keras.metrics.AUC( name='prc', curve='PR' ),
]

# Compile the model
model.compile( optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=METRICS )

epochs_no = 100
batch_size = 2048
model.fit( X_train, y_train, epochs = epochs_no, batch_size = batch_size, class_weight = class_weight )
results = model.evaluate( X_test, y_test, batch_size = batch_size )
print("Loss: {:0.4f}".format(results[0]))


model.save( "./avg_keras_model" )

print( "Total execution time:%s seconds:" % ( time.time() - start_time ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

The **Graph Execution Error** you are facing is not because of the amount of data getting trained. It may just be a mere coincidence.

The underlying cause for the error is simply that the **predictions are not between 0 and 1**.
For the `tf.keras.metrics.TruePositives` metric which you are using, you should make sure that your predictions are between 0 and 1.

With the Sigmoid Activation function which you have correctly applied in the last layer for this binary classification problem, the predictions are expected to be in the range mentioned above. However, it seems **not all predictions** are lying in **{0,1}** and a possibility of **NaNs**.

The easiest way to come around this is to write a custom function for ensuring our outputs are in proper range.

```
def normalize_outputs(x):

    return [round((i - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x)), 2) for i in x]
```